# using c++17 in mql5

Tags: c++, c++17, mql5, mql

Recently I want use all new features of c++(<=c++17) in MQL5 , Or using c++ stl containers , like std::map , std::vector.

I can do something like this:

> creating a wrapper on them and compile them , hence using dll in mql5
> But it's so bad idea , Can anyone suggest better way?  thx for answer.

I know that features like **template overloading** and more features should be suppoerted by meta trader code base , but they are so slow in this way , I wanna use new features in indirect way now, if it's possible.